# How to set email subject of AWS SNS email through node-red MQTT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, amazon-sns, node-red, aws-iot

I am trying to create a simple IoT system with a temperature sensor using node-red and AWS IoT. When the temperature reaches a certain point, it will send an email through AWS SNS.
I have managed to make the system works as intended. However, the email I am receiving has the subject "AWS Notification Message". How to customize this title?

Some more detail: the rule is created in node-red, so node-red will only publish a warning message to AWS IoT when the temperature limit has been reached. AWS IoT only forward the content of the message to AWS SNS.

What I have tried so far: 
Setting the SNS email as JSON and RAW. In the case of RAW, there seems no way to set the subject. When I tried JSON, I used the following content as the message published through MQTT:

```
{
    "subject" : "Warning message",
    "message" : "The temperature has reached 30deg"
}
```

However, when I set it as JSON the email never arrives.

Thank you.